# Timing of multiple offers

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, internship, job-change

I had an interview last week with a company that I'm really interested in and they called me two days ago to let me know that I got offered the role.

The issue is, this past Sunday I had an interview with another company which is like my dream job, and the pay is much higher! After the interview on Sunday, the recruiter mentioned how interested she is with my experience and all that which really gave me hopes.

The company that offered me the role will be sending me the contract to read on this coming Sunday and they expect me to reply back on Monday. The "dream job" company said that they'll let me know by next week if I'm in or not.

Now, I wouldn't mind taking the offer but I do not want to deal with the embarrassment of leaving on the first week in case I got accepted in the "Dream job" company.

How should I proceed without ruining either opportunity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet here is to simply call up the company you accepted the offer with and ask them if you can delay your start date by a week or so.

This way, you give the other company time to make a decision with out risking the offer in hand, *and* you don't start a job just to turn around and give your notice.

Comment: Makes sense! In case there's already a start date on the contract, what do I do about that? I can't call today nor tomorrow, it's the weekend in here.

Comment: All you can do is ask if they will amend the start date.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I accepted the offer over the phone but I told them that I need to read the contract before making any further decision. They mentioned that the contract will have a start date. I'm not sure how to ask them to extend (once they send it in). I'm sure the starting date is within next week.

Answer (score 3):

Because you haven't signed the contract you have zero obligation. You don't have any idea if the terms in the contract will be what you expect. You have no idea when the start date will be. They have said that they want an answer by Monday, which means you don't have to make a decision before then.

When you get the written offer, and assuming it is acceptable, and doesn't have any conditions such as background check or other things that will take time to address; then contact the company that is promising an offer next week and let them know you have an offer and you want to know if they are ready to make a decision.

If the "dream job" company needs a couple of days to send you an offer, see if you can delay the deadline from the first company by a couple of days.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! That's my concern, this company seems to want me to start ASAP, I already asked them to extend a day for me to see if I'll accept the offer or not